# How to retrieve a content builder asset by it's legacyId with REST API call?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, rest, content-builder, rest-service

When I fetch all assets, in assets response JSON there is a JSON object name lagecyData:

```
"legacyData": {
    "legacyId": XXXXX,
    "legacyKey": "XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "legacyType": "email",
    "legacyCategoryId": XXXX
  }
```

Now I want to retrieve a specific asset by it's lagecyId. There is any way to retrieve assets by lagecyId.

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what way do you want to retrieve it? It sounds like you already retrieved it inside the JSON.

Comment: `/asset/v1/content/assets` API fetch all asset. But I need specific asset by lagecyId. Means fetch all assets where `lagecyId` equal to `xxxxx`. Now I think you understand my problem.

Comment: Almost - why does it need to be legacyId and not the content id?

Answer (score 2):

If it must be the legacy Id, you will likely need to do via a query using [POST /asset/v1/content/assets/query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/assetAdvancedQuery.htm).

Example:

```
Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
POST //asset/v1/content/assets/query
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
    "page":
    {
        "page":1,
        "pageSize":50
    },

    "query":
    {
        "leftOperand":
        {
            "property":"version",
            "simpleOperator":"equal",
            "value":1
        },
        "logicalOperator":"AND",
        "rightOperand":
        {
            "property":"assetType.name",
            "simpleOperator":"equal",
            "value":"Template"
        }
    },

    "sort":
    [
        { "property":"id", "direction":"ASC" }
    ],

    "fields":
    [
        "enterpriseId",
        "memberId",
        "thumbnail",
        "category",
        "content",
        "data"
    ]
}
```

**My recommendation:**
If you can use the Content ID, I would instead recommend `GET /asset/v1/content/assets/{id}` Which lets you look up details on a specific asset without any queries needed.

Comment: I have resolved my problem using this API format: `/asset/v1/content/assets?$filter=data.email.legacy.legacyId%20eq%20'98987"`
Is it the correct way of doing this?

Comment: it is one of the ways. I sincerely would recommend using the GET instead if possible. It is a more efficient call and is made specifically for that usage. But if your use case requires legacy id, the filter/query will work

Comment: Also, please make sure to mark all answer that resolve your question. So that anyone else having this issue will be able to better find their answer as well.

Comment: @Gortonington How does this actually query by the legacy ID? I don't see any reference to `legacyId`

Comment: The query was a sample. You would add legacyid to the filter part('query') instead of my example properties

Comment: @KrishanKantSharma has the simplest solution, IMO.  I was able to retrieve the asset by legacy id using what he provided.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs - it all depends on what you want returned. If you want the quickest to implement, then the filter is probably the best. If you want the one that gives you the most control/customization on filtering and returned fields, then the POST is best. If you want the most efficient, then you would use the GET with ContentID.